How to apply a conditional class in vue composition api if a variable have value
I need to apply a class conditionally for my vue project. I have defined some props that will pass the class to a component conditionally. In this case, I don't know what's the best way to proceed. I will need to have a class if a variable has a value. At the moment I have a variable that is always true, so the class will be always be applied.
:class="[  
 props.class,
 {
  'pb-2x': isUsable,
  'min-h-[calc(100-vh_-_96px)]': minHeight,
  'min-h-100vh': minHeight && isUsable
 }
]"

At the moment the minHeight is set by default on true in this way
const props = withDefaults(
 defineProps<{
  minHeight: boolean
 }>(),
 {
   minHeight: true
 }
);

The condition I need to check is imported from a composable
import { checkUser } from "./utils/userCheck.ts"

const { isUserOk } = checkUser();

This const will have a string and will be undefined when page load, will be valorized only if the user will click on a button so the back-end will send the value to it.
What is the best way to proceed and have a class switch when needed? Will I need a ternary operator or a coalescing?
Can someone help me?

minHeight ? 'min-h-[calc(100-vh_-_96px)]' : '' should be enough no?

@kissu minHeight will be always true and I need to switch the class with another if the isUserOk have a value, not sure this will work as expected?

@JaromandaX the ckass is similar, but it will remove other 70px to the calc min-h-[100-vh_-_96px_-_70px]

@JaromandaX it's simple. I want the class I show you into the comment that replace the one that actually is passed

@JaromandaX all three classes are passed, but on the third I will need to change it according to the value of the isUserOk

This is solvable as described here. The example they have given was
<div :class="{ active: isActive }"></div>

of course, instead of isActive you can use your condition.

I know, but this will check for boolean values as i know? I have a string in the isUserOk

@newbiedev you can check whether it's empty, which is a boolean criteria. You can implement a function that returns boolean and use that here. Instead of isActive, you could have !!yourString (untested)
